# In Azure, I'm having trouble getting port 10020 to expose

Tags: networking, azure

I have a CentOS/Linux VM installed and I'm having trouble making port 10020 available for external use. Here's a screenshot of my network configuration:

[image: Screen shot of Azure network configuration]

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation, it seems that the port is unexposed if I specify the source port range to be port 10020. If I instead specify the source port range to be "*", the port is available.